# What is the equivalent of "QString text = tr("%1...").arg(QString(format).toUpper());" from QT C++ to PyQt5 (Python)?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I tried something like:

```
text = self.tr("%1...").arg(str(format).upper())
```

but I get the error 'str' object has no attribute 'arg'. I think QString has been deprecated from PyQt5.
I also don't know how to translate to Python:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save As"),
                               initialPath,
                               tr("%1 Files (*.%2);;All Files (*)")
                               .arg(QString::fromLatin1(fileFormat.toUpper()))
                               .arg(QString::fromLatin1(fileFormat)));
```

Comment: I'm a little confused with what you are trying to do. Make the C++ code into python? It looks like two issues but I'm not sure what you are asking?

Comment: Yes. I took the code from a tutorial for a drawing app from here: http://www.newthinktank.com/2018/07/qt-tutorial-5-paint-app/ which is made in C++. I want to make this app in Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The translation of an application from Qt/C++ to PyQt5 (or PySide2) is largely trivial but in some details there is no direct translation so you should understand what that line of code does. In your case tr() returns the translated text which is a QString that does not exist in python, and arg() returns a string replacing the marker(%1 and %2) with the passed value, so in python you can use format, %X or the f-string:

```py
fileName = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
    self,
    self.tr("Save As"),
    initialPath,
    self.tr("{} Files (*.{});;All Files (*)").format(fileFormat.upper(), fileFormat),
)
```